# Merge pull replication failes with error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replication

## 2017-07-19 09:04:17.542 [0%] [944896 sec remaining] Web synchronization progress: 94% complete.

## Article Upload Statistics:

```
FILE_REPLICA:
    Relative Cost: 4.87%

PUBLISH_DOCUMENTS:
    Updates: 827
    Relative Cost: 76.73%

WF_ACTIVE_ROUTING_HISTORY:
    Relative Cost: 4.29%

WF_RUN_ROUTING_HISTORY_REV:
    Relative Cost: 1.87%

WF_RUN_STAGE_RES_LIST_PRES:
    Relative Cost: 1.83%

WF_RUN_STAGE_STATUS_PRES:
    Relative Cost: 1.83%

ORDER_RES_GROUP:
    Relative Cost: 5.54%

WF_RUN_ROUTING_HISTORY:
    Relative Cost: 3.04%
```

## Article Download Statistics:

```
FILE_REPLICA:
    Relative Cost: 7.61%

PUBLISH_DOCUMENTS:
    Relative Cost: 4.18%

WF_ACTIVE_ROUTING_HISTORY:
    Relative Cost: 29.20%

WF_RUN_ROUTING_HISTORY_REV:
    Relative Cost: 13.25%

WF_RUN_STAGE_RES_LIST_PRES:
    Relative Cost: 19.39%

WF_RUN_STAGE_STATUS_PRES:
    Relative Cost: 6.54%

ORDER_RES_GROUP:
    Relative Cost: 9.05%

WF_RUN_ROUTING_HISTORY:
    Relative Cost: 10.78%
```

## Session Statistics:

```
    Upload Updates: 827

    Deadlocks encountered: 18
    Change Delivery Time: 753 sec
    Schema Change and Bulk Insert Time: 5 sec
    Delivery Rate: 1.10 rows/sec
    Total Session Duration: 6556 sec
```

=============================================================
2017-07-19 09:04:17.596 Connecting to Subscriber 'VMSQL2014'
2017-07-19 09:04:17.609 The upload message to be sent to Publisher 'VMSQL2014' is being generated
2017-07-19 09:04:17.613 The merge process is using Exchange ID '86D0215F-E4E3-4FC1-99F4-BC9E05ACDA21' for this web synchronization session.
2017-07-19 09:04:20.168 Uploading data changes to the Publisher
2017-07-19 09:04:22.980 A query executing on Subscriber 'VMSQL2014' failed because the connection was chosen as the victim in a deadlock. Please rerun the merge process if you still see this error after internal retries by the merge process.
2017-07-19 09:04:25.513 [0%] [1227049 sec remaining] Request message generated, now making it ready for upload.
2017-07-19 09:04:25.561 [0%] [1227049 sec remaining] Upload request size is 260442 bytes.
2017-07-19 09:04:27.462 [0%] [1227049 sec remaining] Uploaded a total of 55 chunks.
2017-07-19 09:04:27.466 [0%] [1227049 sec remaining] The request message was sent to 'https://webserver/SQLReplication/replisapi.dll'
2017-07-19 09:09:28.676 The operation timed out

2017-07-19 09:09:28.679 Category:NULL
Source:  Merge Process
Number:  -2147209502
Message: The operation timed out

2017-07-19 09:09:28.680 Category:NULL
Source:  Merge Process
Number:  -2147209502
Message: The processing of the response message failed.

Answer (score 0):

It says there were deadlocks encountered. A [deadlock](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177433(v=sql.105).aspx) is when two transactions are trying to affect the same row. Likely, someone / some other program is writing to the same row you want to write to, thus locking you out and not letting you write.

You can:

1. Implement a [retry procedure](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3188/implementing-sql-server-transaction-retry-logic-for-failed-transactions/) so your merge tries again if deadlocked.
2. Lock your database out from other programs / users while you run this.

There are likely other options to get around this issue. Google: "avoid deadlock"